# How can I automatically reject some types of calls?

Tags: call-screening

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reliably screen or block callers on a number-by-number basis?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/how-can-i-reliably-screen-or-block-callers-on-a-number-by-number-basis)

I've been getting calls from a strange number recently, and it's not even a local area call. This caller has called me 20 times, and whenever I pick up the phone I am met with intimidating silence, even if I shout in it.

Naturally, I decided that I had enough, and tried to surf the internet finding ways to block certain phone number. However, the only methods I found were to either:

(1) Call your call service company to block a call,

(2) Install some apps to do it,

Now, I do not want to overcomplicate this situation, and I've had bad experiences with applications... so, any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try blacklisting the phone no. Long press the phone no. in the Call Logs and select 'Add to Blacklist' option.