# Can I configure my Android Phone to block certain numbers calls?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, calls, call-screening

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reliably screen or block callers on a number-by-number basis?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/how-can-i-reliably-screen-or-block-callers-on-a-number-by-number-basis)

I'm receiving calls from call-center companies that wan't to offer me services that I don't want. I already ask them to stop calling but they keep trying.. Can I configure my 2.2 Android Phone(Galaxy 551) to block the incomming calls from certain numbers?

Comment: @Mathew the Question you point to is only resolved if you can use Google Voice service. At this time this service is not available in many countries.

Comment: I my contry, Brazil, google voice is still unavaiable for Android.

Comment: @Doliveras: There are two other answers there which do not require Google Voice, both of which work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about an option in the system itself but the app mr number will do that for you: 
The lifehacker article talks about the app http://lifehacker.com/5648876/call-block-unlimited-automates-call-blocking-and-routing-on-android-phones

Comment: I use this app too. It have a comunity list with telemarketers reported by the users. very powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

Not positive which version they added the feature or if this is an HTC/T-Mo addition, but on my HTC G2 (running 2.3.3) it can be done without any apps.

While viewing a contact, I can go into the menu -> options and change the ringtone or route calls directly to voicemail. I configured this for a single contact I've called "Blocked" and add numbers to this contact as needed.

Even better, within Google Voice, which I use for voicemail, I go to this entry, edit the Google Voice settings for that entry, and change the selection from which phones to ring to block the caller.

Now my phone doesn't ring and I don't get any voicemails to delete.

Comment: I didnt find this option on my Galaxy 551.... However, thank you...