# blocking individual numbers & text messages for Android phones

Tags: call-screening

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reliably screen or block callers on a number-by-number basis?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9977/how-can-i-reliably-screen-or-block-callers-on-a-number-by-number-basis)

Had Easy Filter app and it worked great for a while on my Samsung Galaxy, then it stopped.  Question which phone does the Easy Filter work well with?  Or which Android phones are compatible with which call blocking apps.  Need to block specific numbers from incoming calls and text messages.

Answer (score 4):

[Anti SMS Spam](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.baole.app.antismsspam) works great, also see [Mr. Number](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker) for good call management.